# Vue.js pasing object to orher components

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Hello i have a login page, i want to fill my account with the response i get from the API and then use it in my header and elsewhere. my header i rendered in my app.vue. how do i acces the account filled with the object

here is my code.

```
    <template>
    <div class="rating-login-view">
    <div class="rating-login-view__form">
      <span></span>
      <form class="login-form">
        <h1 class="login-form__greeting">Velkommen til <span class="break large">Lorem Ipsum</span></h1>
        <label class="login-form__username" for="username">
          <span>Brugernavn</span>
          <input class="input-username" id="username" type="text" name="username" v-model="username" placeholder="Butik">
        </label>
        <label class="login-form__password" for="password">
          <span>Kodeord</span>
          <input class="input-password" id="password" type="password" v-model="password" name="password" placeholder="*********">
        </label>
        <input class="login-form__submit" type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="login()" value="Log in">
      </form>
      <p class="customer-help">Brug for hjælp? Ring +45 50 500 500</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-login-view__image">
      <span class="organisation">
        <img class="organisation-logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    import {Account} from './js/account.js'

    export default {
      name: 'login',
      data () {
        return {
          username: '',
          password: '',
          account: ''
        }
      },
      methods: {
        login () {
          axios.post('MYAPI', {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
           }).then(response => {
             console.log(this.username)
        console.log(this.password)
        console.log(response)
        if (!response.data.Error) {
          if (response.data.status.type === 0 || response.data.status.type === 1) {
            this.$session.start()
            this.account = response.data
            Account.$emit('account fill', this.account)
            // this.$session.set('jwt', response.body.token)     // gives a key and a value to the session
            // Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.body.token   // security
            // this.$router.push('/dashboard')

            console.log(this.account)
          }
        } else {
          alert('something went wrong')
        }
      })
    }
  }
        }
        </script>

      <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
      <style>
```

i want to use the filled account somewhere else than in this component

Comment: I recommend you to make use of [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to store the account details, so you can access it from any component.

Comment: but then i have to remake my whole app to use vuex?

Comment: I don't think so, you can implement it partially, only in the places that you would like to use it. I believe that worth you giving vuex a change for this occasion, even more because you are handling a user, which usually is used (believe me) in more than one component. You can do as it is done in this [article - Persisting user authentication with Vuex in Vue](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/persisting-user-authentication-with-vuex-in-vue-b1514d5d3278)

Comment: Another option which I wouldn't do, but it is an option, you can do instead of `this.$emit('logged', this.account)` and on the parent of login, which is where you call the login component you would do `<login v-on:logged="functionToReceiveAccountDetails">...</login>` in the parent you need to have declared `methods: { functionToReceiveAccountDetails(account) { console.log(account); } }`
With that you can pass set the data in the parent component and then [pass to children components using props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)

Comment: okay ill try the vuex solution

Comment: the structure of vue x is a whole lot different like ive made it, but what you mean is i can create a vuex store and then fill it up from my login fucntion and use the data in other components?

Comment: Exactly! You got it :)

Comment: nice, i actually found a solution that does the most of the work for me with security,  i used something thats called vue-session and then i could parse my data into this session. its a npm called vue-session

Answer (score 0):

Create an object variable **obj1** in the Master page(You can create this variable at the top of head section so that it is available before any script runs). You can access this variable from any component you want. Let's say you want to store an object **obj2** from the component. In your component store **obj2** like this --

```
obj1.obj2 = obj2;
```

From any other component you can access it using **obj1.obj2**

Comment: but lets say i create this obj on app.vue and then fill it on my login page. and then use it on another component? is that possible with this solution?

Comment: <template>
  <div id="app">
      <Header></Header>
    <main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/Header'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'Header': Header
  }
}
</script>

<style lang='scss'>
@import './assets/style/style';
</style>

my code looks like this on my masterpage. where do i put the obj variable then?

Comment: Master page means where your html, head or body element is placed